# Deserialize two element string in JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have the following string,

```
[{ "AnimalName" : "Gatto", "Year" : 5.0 }, { "AnimalName" : "Gatto", "Year" : 6.0 }]
```

I want to Deserialize this string using the class Animali

```
public class Animali
    {
        public string AnimalName { get; set; }
        public double Year { get; set; }
    }
```

I use the following code,

```
Animali json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Animali>(string);
```

My problem is that having two separate element, I receive the error;

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: ,. Path '', line 1, position 40.'

What is the correct way to deserialize the string? Any suggestion?

P.S. Using one elemente like `[{ "AnimalName" : "Gatto", "Year" : 5.0 }]` the code works correctly.

Comment: You have multiple animal now, you should be expecting a `Animali[]` or `List<Animali>`.

Comment: Ohhh,ok. Now is clear. With this code the Json works correctly `List<Animali> jsonReal2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <List<Animali>>(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data));` Thanks so much @Xiaoy312!!

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out, your json is an array, and you need to deserialize it as such

```
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Animali>>(string);
```

Example from the json site

[Deserialize a Collection](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeCollection.htm)

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to parse your json string into JToken.
2. Cast your JToken to List.

Here I created a console app for your demonstration purpose.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"[{ 'AnimalName' : 'Gatto', 'Year' : 5.0 }, { 'AnimalName' : 'Gatto', 'Year' : 6.0 }]";

        JToken jToken = JToken.Parse(json);                         //Point No. 1
        List<Animali> animalis = jToken.ToObject<List<Animali>>();  //Point No. 2

        foreach (Animali animali in animalis)  //Print result
        {
            Console.WriteLine("AnimalName: " + animali.AnimalName + "\t Year: " + animali.Year);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]